# "The Stars and Stripes" vs. "Old Glory" vs. "The Star-Spangled Banner"

Tags: differences, american-english, word-usage, dialects

Is there a difference in using any which of those terms to call the national flag of the U.S.?

Which one is most commonly used?

> **The Stars and Stripes**
>
> The national flag of the U.S., consisting of 13 horizontal stripes, alternately red and white, and a blue field containing white stars representing the states. Also called *Old Glory*, *The Star-Spangled Banner*. [1782, Amer.]
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stars-and-stripes)
>
> **The Star-Spangled Banner**
>
> 1. Stars and Stripes.
> 2. (italics) the national anthem of the United States of America, based on a poem written by Francis Scott Key on September 14, 1814, and set by him to the melody of the English song To Anacreon in Heaven: officially adopted by the U.S. Congress in 1931.
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/the-star-spangled-banner)
>
> **Old Glory**
>
> The flag of the United States
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Old%20Glory)

Comment: *Stars and Stripes* is least likely to lead to confusion, when the context does not establish the meaning.  *Old Glory* is what someone may call their mother-in-law, and *The Star-Spangled Banner* is most tightly associated with the song.

Comment: Note that "the stars and stripes" concept is well known also outside the US, *un drapeau avec des étoiles et des rayures*, *una bandiera a stelle e strisce*, etc.

Comment: From what I know, Star-Spangled Banner refers either to the anthem, or to the *specific* 15-star and 15-stripe flag that flew over Fort McHenry during the British bombardment in 1814.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the common term, "American Flag"?

Comment: I'm not sure if Hot Licks calls his mother-in-law Old Glory, but that expression definitely doesn't remind me of a mother-in-law.

Comment: @StevenLittman - It's all in how you say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The%20Stars%20and%20Stripes%2CThe%20Star-Spangled%20Banner%2C%20Old%20Glory&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CThe%20Stars%20and%20Stripes%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20Stars%20and%20Stripes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20stars%20and%20stripes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20Stars%20and%20Stripes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20stars%20and%20stripes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTHE%20STARS%20AND%20STRIPES%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CThe%20Star%20-%20Spangled%20Banner%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BThe%20Star%20-%20Spangled%20Banner%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20star%20-%20spangled%20banner%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20Star%20-%20Spangled%20Banner%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20Star%20-%20spangled%20Banner%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20Star%20-%20spangled%20Banner%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20star%20-%20spangled%20banner%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTHE%20STAR%20-%20SPANGLED%20BANNER%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2COld%20Glory%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BOld%20Glory%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bold%20glory%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOLD%20GLORY%3B%2Cc0)*** *The Stars and Stripes*  looks the more common.

Comment: The Star-Spangled Banner does refer to the American flag, specifically the one flying over Fort McHenry during the attack in 1814, but it could refer to the current flag as well.  The reason it's not used that frequently probably is that this particular expression is closely associated with the national anthem, not the flag itself.  There is a famous march tune called The Stars and Stripes Forever as well. But since the word Forever is included, it's less likely that saying the Stars and Stripes would lead someone to think of the march, which is also less famous than the national anthem.